# Synapse serverless TPC-H Query15 wrong syntax

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying the TPC-H Queries, they all worked fine except Number 15, basically supplier_no was not recognized, do you know how to rewrite it, the only change I made for all Queries is to replace limit by top

```
SELECT
    --Query15
    s_suppkey,
    s_name,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    total_revenue
FROM
    supplier,
    (
        SELECT
            l_suppkey AS supplier_no,
            SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS total_revenue
        FROM
            lineitem
        WHERE
            l_shipdate >= CAST('1996-01-01' AS date)
            AND l_shipdate < CAST('1996-04-01' AS date)
        GROUP BY
            supplier_no
    ) revenue0
WHERE
    s_suppkey = supplier_no
    AND total_revenue = (
        SELECT
            MAX(total_revenue)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    l_suppkey AS supplier_no,
                    SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS total_revenue
                FROM
                    lineitem
                WHERE
                    l_shipdate >= CAST('1996-01-01' AS date)
                    AND l_shipdate < CAST('1996-04-01' AS date)
                GROUP BY
                    supplier_no
            ) revenue1
    )
ORDER BY
    s_suppkey;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the following errors you just need to make sure that you are referring to the source column name (`l_suppkey`) in this case, not the alias (`supplier_no`) in this case:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'supplier_no'.
>
> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Each GROUP BY expression must
> contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

A full statement which has been tested against a dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics:

```
SELECT
    --Query15
    s_suppkey,
    s_name,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    total_revenue
FROM
    supplier,
    (
        SELECT
            l_suppkey AS supplier_no,
            SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS total_revenue
        FROM
            lineitem
        WHERE
            l_shipdate >= CAST('1996-01-01' AS date)
            AND l_shipdate < CAST('1996-04-01' AS date)
        GROUP BY
            l_suppkey
    ) revenue0
WHERE
    s_suppkey = supplier_no
    AND total_revenue = (
        SELECT
            MAX(total_revenue)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    l_suppkey AS supplier_no,
                    SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS total_revenue
                FROM
                    lineitem
                WHERE
                    l_shipdate >= CAST('1996-01-01' AS date)
                    AND l_shipdate < CAST('1996-04-01' AS date)
                GROUP BY
                    l_suppkey
            ) revenue1
    )
ORDER BY
    s_suppkey;
```

NB SQL Server has the ability to refer to the alias in the `ORDER BY` statement but not the `GROUP BY`.

### Re related discussion on performance on Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pools:

Just for fun, I repartitioned my TPC-H SF10 `dbo.lineitem` table by `l_shipdate`, added the `filepath()` metadata function to filter on and got the warm query down to 1 sec, 7 seconds on first run.  So some caching did seem to be in play.

I realise you have **not** had to do these very query-specific optimisations for the other platforms but I wanted to see if it was possible to improve the performance.

I suppose Q14 is to test specific transformation rules in the respective db engines:[image: tpch q14 minor serverless rewrite]

The query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
    l_suppkey,
    SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS total_revenue
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'enriched/tpch/tpch10/lineitem_partitioned/*/*.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'MyDataSource',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) x
WHERE x.filepath(1) = 1996
  AND l_shipdate Between CAST('1996-01-01' AS DATE) And CAST('1996-04-01' AS DATE)
GROUP BY l_suppkey
)
SELECT
    s.s_suppkey,
    s.s_name,
    s.s_address,
    s.s_phone,
    c.total_revenue
FROM ext.supplier s
    INNER JOIN cte c ON s.s_suppkey = c.l_suppkey
WHERE total_revenue = ( SELECT MAX(total_revenue) FROM cte );
```